# How to select value from one column based on values from different column?

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a list of characters as such:

```
list <- c("dog", "cat", "fish")
```

and I have a df as such:

```
df = tibble(animal = c("dog", "fish", "frog", "cat", "shark"), plant = c("tree", "daisy", "mushroom", "grass", "dafodil"))

print(df)

# A tibble: 5 × 2
  animal plant   
  <chr>  <chr>   
1 dog    tree    
2 fish   daisy   
3 frog   mushroom
4 cat    grass   
5 shark  dafodil
```

I would like to generate a list of plants corresponding to the list of animals above, which would look like :

```
plant_list 
c("tree", "grass" "daisy")
```

I have tried

```
plant_list <- c()

for (i in list){
  if (df$animal == i){
    plant_list <- append(plant_list, df$plant)
  } else {}
}
```

but this gives me an error. What is a good solution ?(preferably with dplyr, but anyway would be great!)

Comment: I would like to query the df, and produce a list of plants corresponding to the animals in the list provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
anmal <- c("dog", "cat", "fish")
df %>%
  filter(animal %in% anmal) %>%
  pull(plant)

[1] "tree"  "daisy" "grass"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use -

```
df$plant[df$animal %in% list]
#[1] "tree"  "daisy" "grass"
```